# Swift Package Manager issues with unversioned Packages (example: firebase-ios-sdk)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift-package-manager

I'm working on pulling out some of the functionality on one of my apps into a package so that I can centralize some reused code, and in doing so I pulled the dependency to firebase into my package. As soon as I did this, I can no longer get updates to my package because of the following error:

**Failed to resolve packages**

> because no versions of mobile.ios.MYPACKAGE match the requirement 1.0.7..<2.0.0 and package mobile.ios.MYPACKAGE is required using a version-based requirement and it depends on unversion package firebase-ios-sdk, mobile.ios.MYPACKAGE >=1.0.6 is forbidden.
> And because root depends on mobile.ios.MYPACKAGE 1.0.6..<2.0.0, version solving failed.

This error makes sense since my `Package.swift` has a reference to `firebase-ios-sdk`, which is currently in beta. This is alright because I don't plan on releasing my pacakge till firebase exits their beta later this year.

My reference to the package inside of dependencies array:

```
dependencies: [
    .package(name: "Firebase",
               url: "https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git",
               .branch("6.32-spm-beta")),
...
```

My reference to the firebase package inside of my targets array

```
    targets: [
    .target(
        name: "MYPACKAGE",
        dependencies: ["Alamofire", "SwiftyJSON",
            .product(name: "FirebaseAuth", package: "Firebase"),
            .product(name: "FirebaseCrashlytics", package: "Firebase"),
            .product(name: "FirebaseAnalytics", package: "Firebase"),
```

You can see I'm referencing the `6.32.spm-beta` as firebase instructs you to do in their docs. How can I get past this issue so that I can work on integrating my package with my application while firebase is still in its beta?

Comment: I am also getting this problem. Probably worth raising as an issue on the Firebase iOS SDK Github repo.

Comment: They actually said to tag them on StackOverflow with the firebase flag for questions. But since nobody from firebase has looked at this in a week, I'll probably do that. (If you beat me to it link it)

Comment: Any news on that?

Answer (score 2):

There is a version based dependency, if you are adding your package by version so you have to add dependencies by version not from branch:

Note: don't forget to tag your commits(in your package).

for example:

```
dependencies: [
    .package(name: "Firebase",
     url: "https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git",from: "1.0.0")
]
```

Comment: I've tried this (also as per the docs of firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/installation-methods - but all I get is Failed to resolve dependencies in Xcode. BTW I'm opening the project using Package.swift which I assume all kids do these days.